# Iconic Places and 820.5: Grandpa's silly math

Tags: riddle, knowledge

This riddle could be considered short and sweet and may need some lateral thinking.

Grandpa says to me with a mischievous smile:

> "Hope you know your famous iconic places or landmarks.
>
> Show that the following equation is correct.
>
> **Taiwan Landmark  NY Landmark  US Iconic Highway = 820.5**"

Bit of a stretch, if you ask me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Taiwan Landmark:

> (Taipei) 101

NY Landmark:

> Times Square

US Iconic Highway:

> Route (root) 66

Equation:

> 101 * sqr(66)

Which equals

> 820.5, approximately.

Comment: Nicely sniped. Shouldn't have concentrated on the formatting so much :-)

Answer (score 9):

The correct value is actually a bit more than 820.52, so the equals sign should probably be a bit wavier.

The maths are

> $101 \times \sqrt{66} \approx 820.527878868..$

Which you can read aloud to get

> "(Taipei) 101" "Times Square" "Route 66"